# bx slider - get height and width of the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, width, bxslider

I'm trying to get the height and width of the images in the bx slider slides, the problem is that each of them (without the loaded first one) returns *zero*.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
$('.slides > li > img').each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var imgWidth = $this.width();
    var imgHeight = $this.height();

    console.log(imgWidth);
    console.log(imgHeight);

})
```

I also tried putting them in a on load function like this:

```
$('.slides > li > img').each(function(){


    $this.on('load', function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var imgWidth = $this.width();
    var imgHeight = $this.height();

    console.log(imgWidth);
    console.log(imgHeight);

 }
})
```

... but it's still not working =\

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/1/

**Edit 2:**

I now see that when the mode is set to fade - the rest of the `<li>` elements are set to display:none. Is there a way to get the image dimensions despite of this?

Comment: Add your html to show what you are trying to select

Comment: I'm guessing only the first image is visible, so the other images are set to display none or something similar, and you can't get the dimensions of a hidden image without some trickery, and are you trying to get the actual dimension of the image, or whatever BX slider sets them to (which would probably the same for all images) ?

Comment: @adeneo I now see that when the mode is set to fade - the rest of the `<li>` elements are set to `display:none`.
Is there a way to get the image dimensions despite of this?

Comment: @jonasnas here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/1/

Comment: @Ziik - Sure, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/3/

Comment: @adeneo Thank you! Can you only explain line 16 `new_img.src = img.src;` please, I'll be very thankfull!

Comment: It creates a new image in memory, and that line sets the source of the new image to the source of the image from the DOM, and once the source is set, the onload handler fires, so the source should be set *after* the onload event handler, as it is in the fiddle.

Comment: @adeneo Oh, I get it. Thank you very much for the explanation. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider hides all but the first image, and hidden images have no dimensions so you have to use the source (literally) to create a new image object, and then get the dimensions from that once the image has loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.normal-slides').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: false,
        pager: false
    });


    $('.normal-slides img').each(function () {
        var img = this;
        var new_img = new Image();
        new_img.onload = function() {
            console.log('imgWidth = ' + this.width)
            console.log('imgHeight = ' + this.height)
        }
        new_img.src = img.src;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you again! Just one more question - is there a way if I write a css rule for the images, let's say `width: 100%` ( http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/4/ ), can I get the the new stretched height and width values of the third slide, because it's originally smaller?

Comment: This gets the actualy size of the image, if you're looking for the size as it would appear in the page, you have to insert the image into the DOM and have it visible on the page, otherwise it won't have those values as it's not really relative to the parent elements before it's visible and where it's supposed to be.

Comment: I thought that this will be the case. Thank you for taking the time to explain all this =]

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like that

```
$('.slider img').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var imgWidth = $this.width();
    var imgHeight = $this.height();

    console.log(imgWidth);
    console.log(imgHeight);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I can't find where is the problem with my code. I've updated your fiddle with part of my code and the problem appears - the height and width of the second image is zero. Here's it http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/1/ 
I've also tried with a callback function and the dimensions are still zero - http://jsfiddle.net/a3BUA/2/

Comment: Oh, please see **Edit 2** to the main post.